# How to configure Wi-Fi hotspot on RPi4 with Ubuntu 20.04 and network created from the 5G modem

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, usb-modem, hot-spot

i have a RPi4 with the SIM8200EA-M2 5G HAT With Antennas connected via USB port to enable the 5G network on it, i need it ti be configured as a Hotspot to allow some devices to connect to it. So i downloaded the Network manager and configured the 10-my-config.yaml
my doubts are what i do not have Ethernet but the network is colled wwan0, so i replaces the on ethernets the definition eth0 with the wwan0. After that i did
`sudo netplan generate` 
and

`sudo netplan apply`

i can see hotspot but can't connect to it. What could be the reason for it?
is there any other configuration to make in order to have non ethernet network enabled as a hot-spot?

````
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
ethernets:
  wwan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
wifis:
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "Raspberry":
        password: "your password here"
        mode: ap```
````

Comment: Nobody never faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write IP address/cidr for your `wlan0` first. Then enable packet forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Check your DHCP server configurations and iptables/nftables rules.